# Expect Script Running Remote Script in Background

Tags: bash, shell, tcl

I have expect script which connects to remote machine and running a script which exist on remote machine however , its takes 15-20 min so i send exit from my expect script.  This break my remote scirpt and i cannot run.

Tried to run as a ;

```
/usr/bin/bash myscript.sh > /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

however this doesnot work.

my expect script looks like;

```
 ........
expect {
        -re ".*#.*"      {  send "/usr/bin/bash myscript.sh > /dev/null 2>&1 &\n";   }
}
expect {
        -re ".*#.*"      { exp_send "exit \r";    }
}
```

By the way there is no nohub on machnie.

Comment: double check your spelling: `nohup`

Answer (score 0):

You need to launch the remote program with [`nohup`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nohup) so that it will ignore the terminal going away. This is a standard Unix programming trick, and is used because the normal configuration is to kill processes (with the `HUP` — **H**ang **Up** — signal) when the user logs out of the terminal from which they were launched to stop them from otherwise behaving badly.

```
expect -re ".*#.*"
send "nohup /usr/bin/bash myscript.sh > /dev/null 2>&1 &\r"
expect -re ".*#.*"
send "exit\r"
```

Comment: as i write in my post , there is no "nohub"  on remote machine

Comment: Assuming the remote login shell is bash, I would recommend sending `disown` after `nohup`

Comment: @zqxwcevrbt I think you just mis-spelt it; nohup (with a `p` at the end) is part of the POSIX.2 standard.